# How can I check my next.js server errors logs on amplify?

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify, next-auth

I have a next.js app that is deployed using amplify. the site next/auth failing for some specific users, and I'm not sure how can I see that failure logs because that occurring on production.

Does anyone know how can I see the server logs & error for the production site?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar issue with next/auth and found the logs I was after by going here in the Amplify Console:

[image: Amplify App settings: Monitoring]

All apps > (your app name) > App settings:Monitoring

I did a search of all log streams.

[image: log stream list]

And found my issue rather quickly:

[image: screencap of log search with issue]

> https://next-auth.js.org/errors#no_secret Please define a `secret` in production. MissingSecret [MissingSecretError]: Please define a...

Answer (score 0):

You can find your API logs with your deployed API id in CloudWatch.

1. Go to your project in AWS Amplify
2. Click on your hosted environment (tab 'Hosting environments')
3. Click on the last tab 'Deploy'
4. Look for the API id in the deploy logs

```bash
    API Lambda@Edge: some-id
```

5. Go to 'Log groups' in CloudWatch
6. Paste the id in Log groups
7. See the log streams for your API

Comment: That just shows requested started & ended logs not further like building server page or log from it

Comment: Exactly. Such kind of log doesn't help. I want to see what the backed type to console.